# Django - can I save DateTime objects that have different timezones in the same column?

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-1.7

If I have a `DateTimeField()` in a model in my app, can I sometimes store a date time with one timezone and sometimes a different timezone?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, you can.

When Django saves the timezone, it saves it as the UTC time in the database. When it goes to display it again in your app, it will look for the `settings.TIME_ZONE` and apply that time zone. If you need to convert it back to a particular time zone, you will also need to store the string of which time zone it is.

More about: [Django Time Zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/).

Comment: If I also have to store the string of which timezone it is (in a separate column?), then it sounds like the short answer is "no".  I think, however, that I can store non-naive datetime values in a `models.DateTimeField()`.